# How to run docker container from remote api?

Tags: docker, containers

I use this command for create new mysql container in docker.

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name containerName -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

I use docker c# api (https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/Docker.DotNet) for connect and manage docker remote api. but i can't figure out how to pass that terminal command to remote api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem with different technique. I use renci.sshnet library to connect linux terminal and i run commands via shh. it is very simple and useful solution for that.

my code like this;

```
  var privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile("my_private_key.ppk");
                var client = new SshClient("my_host_address", port_number, "username", privateKey);
                client.Connect();
                var command = "docker run -p 3306:3306 --name containerName -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest";
                var result = client.RunCommand(command);
```